# Lenovo Desktop 90G9 - Bootloop after 22H2 Update | What to do?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, updates

I recently updated my Lenovo Desktop PC 90G9 to Windows 10 22H2 (before it had 1909). It was urgently necessary. After downloading this update and restarting the PC, Windows told me that the update had failed. Even after several new attempts, it was always the same.

Without further ado, I took the HDD out of the PC, booted it into my main computer and carried out the update there. This actually worked.

After I had removed the HDD from the PC again and installed it in the new PC, the Lenovo could no longer be started. Well, actually it did, but there was a boot loop. Windows tried to start the automatic repair during every boot, but it didn't work.

[image: Automatische Reparatur]

I thought that a clean install would help, but unfortunately in vain.

The boot loop just described remains. Even if I carry out the installation on my main computer and then reinstall the HDD in the Lenovo, the boot loop remains.

I have already activated "CSM" and deactivated "Secure Boot", unfortunately in vain.

I saw that there was someone experiencing the same problem with the exact same model...
https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/189989-unable-rebuild-lenovo-desktop-90g9-4.html

But i didn't find any helpfull informations.
What else can I do?

Comment: CSM should not be activated, and Secure Boot should be activated. Try to follow [this procedure](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/thinkstation_p520c_p520_p720_p920_win10_installation_v1.0.pdf).

Comment: @harrymc That's the problem; I can't even get the ESD-Stick/Windows 10 Installation Medium to boot... There is the same problem as with the HDD: Boot-Screen (Lenovo label appears) and then the windows-logo but then it shuts down and tries to boot again, but it doesn't work and again and again...

Comment: @PeterAndres - If you booted to an installation media and performed a clean install you had to change the boot order to do that, which means, performing that install would have updated the NVRAM on your device.

Comment: Try to upgrade the BIOS to the latest version (seems to be [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/300-series/310s-08asr/90g9/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI&id=5AC6A815-321D-440E-8833-B07A93E0428C)). Even if this version is already installed, the new installation will reinitialize stuff.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you don't understand: It tries to boot the ESD-Media/Windows 10 Stick but it's stuck in a boot loop. I already changed the boot order.

Comment: @harrymc But I when I can't even get into the OS; how am I supposed to make the BIOS Update? The software is required to be installed on the OS and after the succesfull installation you can proceed to the BIOS Update... Or am I wrong?

Comment: I do not know why you think a Lenovo Recovery USB would not be compatible with your Lenovo PC.  I use them all time. So did you downvote a good answer?

Comment: @John Because it didn't help me. I didn't was the one who thought that the recovery tool is not compatible with my device; It was written on the website from lenovo. 

https://prnt.sc/rYZD18IfF9TJ

Comment: Put your model number into the Lenovo support site for your model. Also call Lenovo Support. Their recovery devices are highly reliable.

Comment: @John I already did that. I inserted the S/N into the following website: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/de/lenovorecovery Then I received a email with a link where they said that the recovery tool isn't compatible with my machine. (Look screenshotà

Comment: Something wrong somewhere with your computer.

Comment: @John No not specifically. The BIOS Setting work, the Windows Version 1909 works but no newer version functions at all.

Comment: @PeterAndres - Any confusion I might or might not have comes from the clarity of your question

Comment: To install the BIOS you need to prepare a boot USB on another computer. See [link1](https://jackstromberg.com/2020/02/tutorial-how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-flash-a-lenovo-devices-bios/) and [link2](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/updating-your-bios-from-a-freedos-bootable-usb/), which may help you to get something that works.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your comment, but sadly there is no file named anything with usb bootable or something: https://prnt.sc/El_3oEC-o0oz

Comment: You misunderstand : The links deal with creating a FreeDOS boot media on which you can copy the `.exe` file of the BIOS. You boot FreeDOS and then launch the BIOS installation. Hopefully, FreeDOS might be enough to let it do its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution...

I had this problem for months now.

Just download the iso-file of the windows 10 version 1909 and install it via rufus onto a min 8GB-Stick. (Here you can download the iso-file: https://archive.org/details/win-10-1909-english-x-64) Then install windows with this stick in a normal maneer.

Once you've installed windows (wich should with this stick work fine), download a bios-update exe-file from the official lenovo website: https://support.lenovo.com/de/de/downloads/ds503426-bios-for-windows-10-64-bit-ideacentre-310s-08asr

Just run the exe file and answer all querys with "no" except the "would you like to continue with bios-update" (or something like that). Once the bios update is completed, you can continue in windows and try to download the update-assistant for windows 10 version 22h2: https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10

run the update assistant, proceed the update like you would do at any other computer.

...aaaaannndddd; there you go. You have installed Windows 10 22h2 and can work with the desktop-machine again.